# C# Visual Studio 2019 red squigglies for syntax error not visible when "Open a local folder" file is opened

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I've found that if I open the same C# file in Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.3 in different ways, I can get the red squigglies in the text editor or not.

I am following a tutorial (PluralSight, C# Fundamentals) and I have created a directory that is structured as follows:

- gradebook/

  - src/

    - GradeBook/

      - GradeBook.csproj
      - Program.cs
  - test/

The tutorial instructs me to open the folder using the "Open a local folder" option at the Visual Studio home screen. However, when I do this, there are no red squigglies for errors in my code. However, if I open the project by Ctrl+Shift+O and selecting the "GradeBook.csproj" file listed above, everything seems right with the world.

To clarify, I have included a few screenshots below:

[File opened with: Open a local folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Aab.png)

[File opened with: Open a project/solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjy3R.png)

In case of image problems, the 2 images show a picture of the same `Program.cs` file opened via the two methods mentioned above. The code in the file is as follows:

```
using System;

namespace Gradebook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            
            int x = "L";
            x.grade();
        }
    }
}
```

The first picture (file opened via "Open a local folder") shows no red squigglies under the two syntactically incorrect lines, while the second picture (opened via Ctrl+Shift+O) shows red squigglies.

Does anybody know how I might go about having the entire parent folder opened in the Solution Explorer while also being able to see the red squigglies?

As a final note: I have also noticed that, when the file is opened via the local folder, typing opening/closing braces ("{") doesn't autocomplete as it does when opening the file via the project/solution.

Comment: What exactly are the red squiggles complaining about? What's the error? I'm pretty certain `int` doesn't have a `grade` function and also that you shouldn't be able to assign a string to one.

Comment: I'd suggest these are expected compile errors, and that maybe the real-time compiler doesn't run in the local folder mode because it perhaps doesn't know the full scope of what it will be building against, so it just lets you view the files without any real context. Just a hunch. Someone with more VS in-depth knowledge might know more.

Comment: This happens because when you open as a local folder you're only browsing the files, Visual Studio is not actually loading your project.

When you open the .csproj file Visual Studio knows you're opening a project and loads everything correctly.

It's weird that the tutorial you're following didn't provide a proper solution file with the project and extra files inside.

Comment: I think that to open as you want, the parent folder, you need to create an empty solution project somewhere, then paste the files, on Solution Explorer (inside VS) you click to Show All Files then add these files to your solution. Then add an existing project and choose the csproj file.

Comment: @RafaelF., you appear to have an answer to the problem. However, could you maybe help me preserve the directory hierarchy for the project? I was able to create solutions with Visual Studio 2019 for the both the GradeBook (in the \src\ directory) and the GradeBook.Tests (within the \test\ directory). However, there seems to be some problem when referencing the GradeBook.csproj from the GradeBook.Tests.csproj. I'm guessing it's because of this workaround. I don't understand the solutions enough to work out a fix for this. Perhaps you might be able to shed some light on it?

Comment: What problem exactly did you have?

Comment: @RafaelF., I spent more time wrestling with this problem, and it seems that I cannot duplicate the process that my tutorial is going through without using VSCode. This seems to be a rookie mistake, since I wasn't aware that they were two different programs. Your answer remains the best one. Now, I just need to figure out how to select your reply as the answer on here...

Comment: @calvin.algos it was given as a comment, so you can't. If RafaelF comes back and converts it into an Answer using the Your Answer box below, you'll be able to mark it as accepted. But you can't accept a comment.

Comment: @ADyson thank you very much! That helps me make sense of this process. I didn't want those offering answers to not get credit for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you open as a local folder you're only browsing the files, Visual Studio is not actually loading your project. When you open the .csproj file Visual Studio knows you're opening a project and loads everything correctly. It's weird that the tutorial you're following didn't provide a proper solution file with the project and extra files inside.

To open as you want, the parent folder, you need to create an empty solution project somewhere, then paste the files in the folder, on Solution Explorer (inside VS) you click to Show All Files (otherwise your pasted files won't show) then add these files to your solution (ricght click, add). Then add add the csproj as an existing project (right click on solution, add existing project, VS will let you select it once you try to add it).

Or use VSCode as you did, VSCode is different indeed from Visual Studio :)